# diferencia sizeof() y strlen()

Tags: array, c, string, sizeof

tengo una serie de caracteres almacenados en un array unidimensional y quiero obtener su tamaño. El problema es que cuando procedo con sizeof() me da el tamaño correcto (4) y cuando lo hago con strlen() me da 16 ???? ayuda pls

```
char cad2[] = { 'H','o','l','a' };
int tamaño2 = sizeof(cad2); // IGNORO DIVIDIR EL SIZEOF ENTRE EL TAMAÑO EN BYTES DE UN CHAR (1)
int tamañolen2 = strlen(cad2);
printf("El tamaño de la segunda cadena por sizeof es %i\n", tamaño2); //IMPRIME 4
printf("El tamaño de la segunda cadena por strlen es %i\n", tamañolen2); //IMPRIME 16
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof()` te dice cuántos bytes ocupa una variable. `strlen()` te dice cuántos caracteres hay en una cadena. Pero una cadena no es un mero array de char, es una secuencia de `char` contiguos en memoria que tiene al final del todo un carácter "terminador" para indicar que ya no hay más.

En tu caso, la variable `cad2` ocupa 4 bytes y por eso `sizeof()` te da el tamaño correctamente. Pero no es una cadena "buena", porque no tiene el terminador.

Por tanto `strlen()` va a contar cuántos caracteres hay hasta encontrar un terminador. Ya que en los elementos de `cad2` no hay terminador, `strlen()` seguirá buscando **fuera** de ese array, invadiendo posiciones de memoria contiguas, hasta que *casualmente* encuentre un byte con el valor que espera como terminador. En tu caso eso ha ocurrido tras recorrer 16 posiciones de memoria. Podría haber sido antes, podría haber sido después. Podría haber agotado la memoria de tu programa sin encontrarlo e invadir otras posiciones de memoria que no pertenecen a tu programa (pero cuando esto ocurriera el sistema operativo lo detendría y verías un error de *segmentation fault*)

La solución para que `cad2` se una cadena "buena" es incluir el carácter terminador, el cual es simplemente un byte de valor 0. Por tanto puedes hacer:

```
char cad2[] = { 'H', 'o', 'l', 'a', 0 }
```

Observa que el `0` no va entre comillas (pues si no sería el código ASCII del símbolo `'0`'`, el cual no tiene valor cero.

Con esta definición `strlen()` te dará la respuesta correcta, 4, pero entonces `sizeof()` te dará una incorrecta (5).

En general cabe decir que `sizeof()` no debe usarse para averiguar cuántas letras tiene una cadena. Por ejempl, considera que lo usas en este otro caso, en el que el mensaje se accede mediante un puntero a char:

```
char *mensaje = "Hola que tal estas":
```

`sizeof(mensaje)` te dará 4, porque 4 es el tamaño del puntero (quizás 8 si estás en una arquitectura de 64 bits). En todo caso no es el número de caracteres de la cadena a la que apunta, el cual en cambio sí obtendrías correctamente con `strlen(mensaje)`.

En este caso no es necesario poner el terminador especial, porque el compilador lo hace por tí. Cada vez que pones algo `"entre comillas dobles"` el compilador añade el terminador (byte de valor 0).

No sólo `strlen()` sino todas las funciones de manejo de cadenas (`strcmp()`, `strcpy()`, etc.) dependen de la existencia de ese terminador final.

Comment: *Podría haber agotado la memoria de tu programa sin encontrarlo..* Porque se agotaria? Si la funcion `strlen` en ningun momento reserva memoria, solo lee la memoria..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Con agotar quise decir "llegar a la última dirección reservada". Cuando el operativo carga tu programa le asigna una zona de la memoria RAM y mapea el espacio de direcciones virtuales del proceso de modo que en ciertas de esas direcciones (las que usa para cargar código y datos) el proceso pueda leer y escribir, pero en las restantes no pueda. Si `strlen()` no encuentra el terminador puede acabar por visitar una de esas direcciones protegidas.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` devuelve el tamaño que ocupa en memoria un tipo y se resuelve en tiempo de compilación.

Usar `sizeof` sobre un puntero obtiene el tamaño del mismo y no de lo que haya en la dirección de memoria a la que apunta.

---

`strlen` es una función que calcula la longitud de una cadena terminada en un caracter nulo (0).

Si la cadena no está terminada en un carácter nulo el código seguirá corriendo hasta encontrar un 0 en alguna posición de memoria a la que no debería acceder.

Una posible implementación es:

```
int strlen(const char *cadena){
    int i = 0;
    while (cadena[i])
        ++i;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ambos son métodos diferentes:

### `sizeof()`

Determina el tamaño de una variable o de un tipo de datos, en este caso si haces el *sizeof* al tipo de dato *char*, este devuelve el valor 1 y es correcto, un *char* equivale a un bit.

### `strlen()`

Este devuelve la longitud de una cadena de texto, *char* es un arreglo de caracteres y cuando lo pasas a la función *strlen* debería de devolver la longitud del arreglo de caracteres.

Como observación al declararlo como cadena el *char*, este tiene un delimitador al final, en caso de escribir `char cad2 [] = "hola";` el valor "hola" termina con un delimitador `\0`, quedando en la cadena `"hola\0"`.